# whitespace not trimmed by devise while log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an application running on rails 2.3.14 and I have "devise", "1.0.10" in my gem file. Devise does not seem to be trimming white space character while authentication.

suppose I have a "admin" user and if I try to login using "admin ", it says unable to authenticate you with.......

Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Devise added the ability to strip whitespaces (and does that by default) since version 1.4.0. Unfortunately, we no longer supported Rails 2.3 in such versions. So the best solution is to either override the `email=` or `login=` method in your model to strip the given value or do it directly in your controller.

Comment: in devise.rb file, you have to add `config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]`. `:email` being the field to be stripped of whitespace while authenticating. But i have not tested in Rails 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to use [a custom controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) and [trim yourself the params](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) before calling super